# Is it possible to implement Comet if we don't use PrototypeJs?

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs, comet

Is it possible to implement Comet if we don't use PrototypeJs?

Comment: Please give some more details of what you have done so far. I can think of multiple computing-related meanings of “prototype” and “comet”, so your question is in need of much more information to be reasonably answerable.

Comment: prototype is a javascript framework.so i used it to do ajax engine on the client side and it worked well when i did comet with php.But when i did comet with normal javascript on the client side it worked but it is not working well when more than one users are accessing the same page at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no problem. You can use any other javascript framework or even achieve this goal without using any javascritp framework at all. Write your own javascript to handle XMLHttpObject.